# Quering between two tables in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hql, hive

I have two tables f and t

**f table is**

one : two : three

1   dk  jkdk

179 dsa ppd

90  dsj dat

**t table is**

one  : two : three

0   100 aus

191 200 NZ

I want to compare f.one value with values  t.one and t.two and get return t.three

For example,

if f.one == 90 then value should be aus

expected output:

t.three

aus

NZ

aus

I tried like :

select t.three  from t JOIN (select f.one from f) y where y.one>=t.one AND y.one<=t.two;

and got output as:

aus

aus

Nz

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it right the problem is that the result don't keep the order of table t and that's why it seems mixed.
Change the select to `t.one,t.three` and you'll see its fine.
if the order really matters you can add `order by t.one` in the end